# Make 'visual-studio-15' a synonym of 'visual-studio-2015'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The [visual-studio-15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-15) tag is synonymous with the [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) tag. The former has 21 questions and 5 followers while the latter has 11,879 questions and 1.2k followers. I suggest that we retag all 21 questions (preferred) and possibly remove the tag or make it a synonym to [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015).

Comment: why not just retag?

Comment: That's what I think would be the best option

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The visual-studio-15 tag is synonymous with the visual-studio-2015 tag

Don't know about the tags, but VS "15" is definitely *not* the same product as VS 2015.

VS 2015 is version "14" (*not* 15), see for example [Microsoft Visual Studio - History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) or MS' own announcement [Visual Studio “14” CTP now available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp-now-available/) from before it was baptized as VS 2015.

Likewise, VS "15" refers to the preview builds of the yet unreleased (and not officially named) next major version of VS. Quoting from the official blog [Visual Studio “15” Preview Now Available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/30/visual-studio-15-preview/):

> At Build 2016 we shared a preview of the next version of Visual Studio, which we call Visual Studio “15” (***not to be confused with Visual Studio 2015***).

Comment: Oh really? That's interesting. I wanted to make sure before posting a question. I checked the Microsoft website and it said 'Visual Studio 15, or Visual Studio 2015....'

Comment: @AndrewL. MS has always maintained different (and often confusing) marketing vs. internal versions (for an unrelated example, Office 2013 was version "15" and Office 2016 is version "16"). What's now codenamed VS "15" will be released under its own branding name, yet unknown, when the time comes - but it won't be a patch or update or service pack to VS 2015 for sure.

Comment: I suspected something like that, which is why I tried to look it up to confirm my suspicion. I guess they got me

Comment: And I wonder why MS is not thinking of making these names easy to remember! What's the point of creating such confusion?

Comment: @CinCout For the same reason that the server version of Windows 8.1 is labeled Windows Server 2012 R2 ;-) I am not MS and can't speak for them, but reasonable guess is that (a) end users don't much care about internal version numbers, and (b) MS' own marketing department doesn't either. After all, "*Windows XP*" was arguably sexier than "*Windows NT 5.1*".

Comment: The choices aren't arbitrary, @Grant. There's a very good reason that VS 2015 is version number 14: it is the 14th major release of the Visual C++ development environment. (Well mostly. They skipped version 3 back in 1995 so VC++ 4 would have the same version number as MFC 4 with which it was bundled.) As for why the marketing department chooses to fluctuate between year names, actual version numbers, and other random monikers, I've no idea. But it'd be even more confusing if the dev team used marketing terms; what if the release date slipped? I've downvoted the proposed synonym into oblivion.

Comment: @CodyGray Not that it matters, but they also skipped version 13 (VS 2013 = v12, 2015 = v14) because somebody must not like that number (they skipped 13 for Office, too, MSO 2007 = v12, 2010 = v14).

Comment: It is [a huge problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia), at least in the US market, to sell software numbered 13. Or to have floors in buildings numbered 13.